# Find elements by input type

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying Python and Selenium. My goal is to log myself into Discord (https://discordapp.com/login. But here is the problem. I can't manage to get the email and password box selected. But the worst part is trying to select a textbox on a server... I tried everything, even locating by XPath, but I can't seem to do it right. Also, doing it on ATOM is probably not the best idea since I don't get any error messages :P. Here is a snippet to select the email textbox.

```js
from selenium
import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://discordapp.com/login')
assert 'discordapp' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('textarea')# this is the part where i need help
elem.send_keys('test' + Keys.ENTER)
```

[image: The Sourcecode]

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML in your post as text, so users that are blind and need screen readers can see it too. It also helps with search engines picking it up for future viewers. Avoid pictures if at all possible!

Answer (score 6):

For email this css selector should work :

```
input[type='email']
```

For password :

```
input[type='password']
```

I've tested this code :

```
browser.get("https://discordapp.com/login")


elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='email']")# this is the part where i need help
elem.send_keys("itsolidude@imail.com")

elem1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")# this is the part where i need help
elem1.send_keys("password")    

login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Login']/parent::button")
login_button.click()
```

This worked fine on my machine.

Comment: or he can basically try to find elements using Xpath / CssSelector :) But nice answer ( didnt know that its possible to search elements like this )

Comment: @cruisepandey weird, its only loading the login page for me but still not inputing the text :/

Comment: Did you get any error/exception ? If so, please update here. FYI, I have not written code to click on login button, not sure if that helps. Updated the code with login button too.

Comment: @cruisepandey i updated the code to press enter ... but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the div container and add them into the xpath.

Try the following code and please debug the indents, in case that stackoverflow is not transferring them properly (well, I don't know how to do it nice and correctly.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class loginPage():

    def test(self):
    baseUrl = 'https://discordapp.com/login'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="G:\\webdriver/geckodriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(baseUrl)

    mail = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[3]/div[1]/div/input[contains(@type,'email')]")
    time.sleep(5)
    mail.send_keys("test@gmail.com")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Enter mail adress")

    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[3]/div[2]/div/input[contains(@type,'password')]")
    time.sleep(5)
    password.send_keys("123456789")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Enter password")
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()

ff = loginPage()
ff.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Login To Discord Website using Python and Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
time.sleep(6)

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
username_input.send_keys("enter-your-username-here")


password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys("Enter-your-password-here")


login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
login_button.click()
```